# How is a mat-checkbox within a table only checked when the checkbox is clicked, not when the row of the table is clicked?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

my problem is, that I have a Table, where i have a matcheck-box in every row, to select the data in the row. Unfortunately the checkbox is also declared as clicked, when you click just on the row, where the checkbox is located.

Hopefully you understand my problem.
Thanks in Advance

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="appState.appData.data.objects" #mm>
        <!-- Id Column-->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <!-- Checkbox Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
            <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                          [checked]="merkmaleDescSelection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                          [indeterminate]="merkmaleDescSelection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
                          [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
            </mat-checkbox>
          </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                          (change)="onCheckedMerkmale($event, row)"
                          [checked]="merkmaleDescSelection.isSelected(row)"
                          [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
            </mat-checkbox>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
```

Comment: You need to add the click event to the entire `mat-row`. Share the entire `table` code block!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments, you need to handle the click event on the entire row element.

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
```

becomes

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" (click)="onRowClick(row)">
```

You'll then need to implement `onRowClick(row)` to make the selection. I would guess this implementation will be similar to `onCheckedMerkmale($event, row)`.

Comment: appreciate it. Thanks